# Compare Model to List<string>

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

I have 2 lists I am trying to compare.

List SelectedPersonCodes; is a just a list of strings (obviously)

List CurrentUserLocations; is a list of LocationId, LocationName pairs.

I need to see if any of the CurrentUserLocation locationIds have a match in the SelectedPersonCOdes list, which is made up of locationIds.

I have put together this:

```
    public JsonResult VerifyDetailAccess(int id)
    {
        List<UserLocation> CurrentUserLocation = repo.GetUserLocations();

        List<string> SelectedPersonLocations = repo.GetTrespassedSiteCodes(id);

        bool IsAuth = false;
        foreach (var current in CurrentUserLocation)
        {
            for(var s = 0; s < SelectedPersonLocations.Count(); s++)
            {
                if(current.LocationCode == SelectedPersonLocations[s])
                {
                    IsAuth = true;
                }

            }
        }

        return Json(IsAuth, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

It always comes out false.  The problem is the if statement, I am not getting the values in the SelectedPersonLocations.  How do I expose those values so I can iterate against them?

I have also tried dual foreach:

```
        foreach (var current in CurrentUserLocation)
        {
            foreach (var select in SelectedPersonLocations)
            {
                if(current.LocationCode == select)
                {
                    IsAuth = true;
                }
            }
```

This exposes the value in select, but even if current.LocationCode and select are the same, it still skips setting the flag, so IsAuth stays false.

Comment: Are you looking to rewrite [Enumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx)? (than you seem to be missing `break`)... Or maybe [Enumerable.All](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) - than again logic is somewhat strange..

Comment: "but even if current.LocationCode and select are the same, it still skips setting the flag, so IsAuth stays false." That seems unlikely. Are you certain they're the same? Case sensitive? No extraneous spaces?